# Audio file works with smartface 4.3

Tags: smartface.io

i am trying to play audio mp3 file. It works for ios with device emulator but if you export to xcode it gives error with "no rule to proccess file..." is it problem with the mp3? which format it support? Or it is just a bug of smartface 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to build that project after publishing ?

http://www.dorukcoskun.com/audioTest.rar

I can build that project. Maybe it is related with xCode version ?

Comment: I am using xcode 6.1 and has the same problem with your sample project. If you can able to build problem with my xcode definetly

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest xCode with yosemite, and can you try with empty project ?

Comment: I have updated to xCode with yosemite but i get the same warning and don't play audio files builded project